# What is the probability of 5 cards out of 20 appearing?

Tags: probability, percentages

This is a Yu-Gi-Oh Duel Links question.  It is a mobile application that allows you to duel other players with digital cards.

Only **2** copies of Card A exist in the 20 card deck.

Only **3** copies of Card B exist in the 20 card deck.

Card B can search for Card A.

What is the equation to determine the probability/likelihood of seeing Card A in a 20 card deck?

For example Card A is your win condition, and subsequentlly, drawing card B is also your win condition (since Card B searches for Card A).  Drawing any copy of Card  A or Card B in your opening hand is your win Condition.

> You can only draw 4 cards in your opening hand.

For simplicity, the sample size thresholds can be 
[100]
[1,000]
[10,000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let X be the event that either card A or card B is drawn.
Then, P(x) = $2/20 + 3/20 = 1/4$

Comment: if the 4 card restriction is mandatory, then $P(X) = (4C2 + 4C3)/20C= 0.00206 (approx)$

Comment: So is it a 25% chance to win?

Comment: if the 4 card restriction is mandatory, then $P(X)=(4C2+4C3)/20C4=0.00206(approx)$ 
That is a 2% chance.
If it is not compulsory, then it is a 25% chance

Comment: I do not know what that means, but the 25% chance makes a lot of sense.